# Can we get notifications for upcoming SE beta site deletions?

Tags: discussion, beta-sites

If a beta Stack Exchange site is about to get deleted, will users be given any advance notice, like an e-mail? Such notice would allow users to save some of the better posts before they get deleted.

Comment: When a beta site gets closed, a data dump of all of the posted questions and answers is made available.

Comment: To my knowledge, for each of the sites that *did* get deleted, it was approached differently. I think Gadgets got a fair warning, Atheism was kinda already recognizing it as was AI, but How Stuff Works apparently was sprung pretty swiftly. I think we'll need official word for this one.

Comment: Oh cool - is there an archive of old beta sites that did get deleted?