# Can we have a option to be notified about upcoming beta SE site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, area-51, site-proposal

I recently read this question. [Can we get notifications for upcoming SE beta site deletions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98160/can-we-get-notifications-for-upcoming-se-beta-site-deletions)

My question is - Can I set up notification for new SE beta site? I'm sometimes intersted in new sites to help to make it bigger but I sometimes forgot to look @area51

Comment: As in you want to be notified for all of them? You can already be notified about specific ones by following/commiting

Comment: yes, exactly all of them. It's not that much

Comment: Are you asking to get a notification for those proposals you are not committed to, or you are not following?

Comment: yes, exactly ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about following the [RSS feed](http://area51.stackexchange.com/feeds) of the newest proposals page in your favorite RSS reader?  I can't imagine many people would want email notifications on every single proposal that they're *not* following.

Comment: I do not mean email notification but notification in SE's "Inbox"